# Add annotations to indicate the order of the fields automatically

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

## Motivation:

- I have a DTO class that stores the values of HTML controls (textbox, checkbox, etc.). I want to validate these values, in order of these controls appear in the HTML, in other words, in the same order as default tab index in HTML (This behavior is passed down from the UX of our old mainframe OLTP programs). To implement these validation with reflection, I want to specify the order of the variables in the DTO. There are 100~ HTMLs in our application, so I want to avoid specifying the orders in each DTO manually.
- I have a DTO class that stores the values that will be written to a QSAM file. To write these values to the file with reflection, I want to specify the order of these variables in the DTO. There are 100~ QSAM files in our application, so I want to avoid specifying the orders in each DTO manually.

## Background:

The order of Class.getDeclaredFields() is not specified in Java, so I want to add annotations to fields to indicate order of field like this:

```java
public final class Model {
    @Order(1)
    String item1;

    @Order(2)
    String item2;

    @Order(3)
    String item3;

    @Order(4)
    String item4;
}
```

But it is too tough to add these annotations to all classes.

## Question:

Is there any way to add annotations to indicate the order of the fields automatically?

I had a look around the document of Lombok, but there is no feature like that.

Comment: what "order"? why would there be need of an 'order'? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Fields don't really have an "order", if the fields in a class do require an order an Array or ArrayList could implicate that. If you want to get the order how there are written in the source then reading the Java File would be the better approach than reflection

Comment: “*But it is too tough to add these annotations to all classes.*” Then don’t  add these annotations to all classes.

Comment: You obviously don't care about the actual order beyond it being deterministic if you're happy for something to auto-generate that order for you so why on earth would you bother introducing an annotation??? Surely to get a deterministic order defining an implementation of java.util.Comparator<java.lang.reflect.Field>, maybe simply ordering them alphabetically by name or something similar would be the better and all round cleaner approach???

Comment: Add "motivation" section to desAdd "motivation" section to describe example of what I want to accomplish. cribe example of what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

`Class.getDeclaredFields` is nondeterministic from run to run.
When I need deterministic output, I either sort the result or use [methods that do](http://plumelib.org/plume-util/api/org/plumelib/util/ClassDeterministic.html) (from [this package](https://github.com/plume-lib/plume-util/), which I maintain).

If you want some other order, you can write your own wrapper for the methods that uses a different sorting order.